# opt.step() is not updating the weights of model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

```
    print(self.global_model.state_dict())
    print("total_loss",total_loss)
    total_loss.backward()
    self.opt.step()
    print(self.global_model.state_dict())
```

it's output is

```
('dense1.weight', tensor([[ 0.3997, -0.1907,  0.1120,  0.3016],
        [ 0.1156,  0.0646,  0.1802,  0.3558],
        [ 0.0321,  0.2537,  0.0879,  0.2441],
        [-0.2952, -0.0886, -0.3235,  0.3006]])), ('dense1.bias', tensor([ 0.1927,  0.3048, -0.3551, -0.0302])), ('dense2.weig

total_loss.backward() tensor(2.5806, dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)

('dense1.weight', tensor([[ 0.3997, -0.1907,  0.1120,  0.3016],
        [ 0.1156,  0.0646,  0.1802,  0.3558],
        [ 0.0321,  0.2537,  0.0879,  0.2441],
        [-0.2952, -0.0886, -0.3235,  0.3006]])), ('dense1.bias', tensor([ 0.192
```

We can see total_loss have some value but it is not updating the weights

```
self.opt = torch.optim.SGD(self.global_model.parameters(),lr = 0.01)
```

## Update

If i do

```
            print(self.local_model.state_dict())
            print("total_loss.backward()",total_loss)
            total_loss.backward()
            opt_2 = torch.optim.SGD(self.local_model.parameters(),lr = 0.01)
            opt_2.step()
            self.opt.step()
            print(self.local_model.state_dict())
```

It updates the weights of local model. 
But i need to apply that gradient to other model. So what i will need to do ?

Comment: There's not enough information in this question. How are your class (`self`) and `self.global_model` defined? How are you passing data through your model? How is `total_loss` computed? If I had to guess I would say that either you're breaking the computation graph (using something like `.detach` somewhere) or the value of `total_loss` is independent of the parameters in `global_model`. Either of these issues would result in `total_loss.backward()` not updating the gradients in `global_model`. There's really no way for anyone to determine which unless you post a [mcve].

Comment: I found out i was using **.detach()** to get the value of tensor. I edit that and the problem got solved